# When dragging object (nearly) outside window, how to make window scroll automatically toward that direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, scroll

I use html5 to implement 'drag and drop' http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp.

But my droppable boxes are quite a few and can not all display in the displayed area of a window. Therefore, when I drag an element to the (eg.) bottom droppable box of the window which is out of displayed range, how to make window scroll automatically?

Like the following webpage, where I want to drag image and drop it to the bottom rectangle (the fifth one), which is out of range of displayed area. When I drag image to the end of window, how to make window scroll automatically until the bottom?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5
{
    width:350px;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
}     
</style>     
<script>     
function allowDrop(ev)     
{     
    ev.preventDefault();     
}     

function drag(ev)     
{     
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);     
}     

function drop(ev)     
{     
    ev.preventDefault();     
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");     
    ev.target.innerHTML += data+"droppedHere"+"<br/>";     
}     
</script>     
</head>     
<body>
<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>     
<img id="drag1" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69" />     

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<br>     
</body>
</html>
```

(You can copy above code to the left column http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop, and check result on right. I want to show that in jsfiddle, but no idea why the code doesn't work there)

I noticed Chrome can do this automatically, but not for other browsers like safari.

I also found related solutions like 'scroll functions' or 'detecting mouse out of window'. But I just can't get what I want based on their codes. Highly appreciate it if someone could provide a more detailed/complete version of solution.

Answer (score 2):

What I just discovered is that (at least in Chrome) while the drag event is occurring, all "mousemove" events are deferred, then fire all together after the drop (or cancel) occurs. That kills one idea, but there are a couple others. Here's one: add an absolutely positioned div with a height of 40-50 px to the bottom of the viewport (so it's sticky), and then have a dragenter event to detect that mouse position and scroll the window (and one at the top of course):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5
{
    width:350px;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
}     
#scrollBottomDetect { position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 40px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid red; }
#scrollTopDetect { position: fixed; top: 0; height: 40px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid red; }
</style>     
<script>     
function allowDrop(ev)     
{     
    ev.preventDefault();     
}     

function drag(ev)     
{     
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);     
}     

function drop(ev)     
{     
    ev.preventDefault();     
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");     
    ev.target.innerHTML += data+"droppedHere"+"<br/>";     
}     

function scrollPage(diff) {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, (window.scrollY + diff));
}

</script>     
</head>     
<body>
<div id="scrollTopDetect" ondragover="scrollPage(-10)"></div>
<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>     
<img id="drag1" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69" />     

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>     
<br>     
<div id="scrollBottomDetect" ondragover="scrollPage(10)"></div>
</body>
</html>
```